# Format number in datagridview- If integer then F0, if decimal then F

Tags: vb.net

I need to format all numbers in a datagridview.
If the number is a whole number then do not show the decimal point and if the number has a fraction then do show the decimal point.

I have achieved this by looping through each column and checking if the content is a double/single/decimal and then looping through each row in those columns to check each value whether the number is whole or has a fraction.
But this takes a long time for the application to process since i might have 2000 rows or more with 5 or more columns being double/single/decimal.

I can't find a standard format which does this.

Can anybody help?

```
dgv.SuspendLayout()
For i = 0 To dgv.Columns.Count - 1
    If dgv.Columns(i).ValueType = GetType(Double) Or dgv.Columns(i).ValueType = GetType(Single) Or dgv.Columns(i).ValueType = GetType(Decimal) Then
        'check If the number has a fraction
        For u = 0 To dgv.Rows.Count - 1
            If Not IsDBNull(dgv.Rows(u).Cells(i).Value) Then
                If dgv.Rows(u).Cells(i).Value Mod 1 <> 0 Then
                    'number has a fraction
                    dgv.Rows(u).Cells(i).Style.Format = "F"
                Else
                    'number is an integer
                    dgv.Rows(u).Cells(i).Style.Format = "F0"
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End If
Next
dgv.ResumeLayout()
```

Comment: "But this takes a long time for the application to process since i might have 2000 rows or more with 5 or more columns being double/single/decimal."  - that shouldn't take more than a few milliseconds. Have you profiled your code to find out what's going on?

Comment: No I haven't profiled it. I don't see the problem in my relatively small database, but I see it in production. I have replaced the code in the question with this dev.columns(i).Defaultcellstyle.Format = "F2", then the datagridview presents the data almost instantly, but if I use the code from the question then it takes at least a minute (i killed the application since it were obviously too slow

Comment: This is something that is usually done in the [DataGridView.CellFormatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview.cellformatting) event, or initializing the Column with a specific [DataGridViewCellStyle.Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcellstyle.format), also defined in the DGV's designer, if you have pre-defined Columns. So, all formatting is performed when needed.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Datagridview.CellFormatting event seemed to solve the issue - Thanks Jimi. I just can't understand the difference between using the event and setting the format in a loop after populating the datagridview